# UI Testing slow ever since Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

Has anyone else experienced this? Our UITests take much longer now to execute than before. Each tap or scroll animation seems to have a long pause in between. Sometimes there will be random test failures because of errors like the one below:

```
Assertion Failure: <unknown>:0: UI Testing Failure - Failure getting snapshot
```

Is there some kind of setting that Apple wedged into Xcode 8 that I am perhaps unaware of? Or how can I resolve this?

Comment: do you use `swift` and which device you use?  if use the `mac min` and `swift` `xcode 8.1`, it will become slow, this is my experience.

Comment: The UI tests are written in swift yes, and the code base of the app is split between legacy Objective C code and new Swift code. MacBook pro so it is definitely not a hardware issue. Just all of a sudden, moving up from XCode 7.x to XCode 8.x just made it slow

Comment: @ascendancy05 out of curiosity do you have Code Coverage or Debug executable checked in our scheme? I unchecked those and it seemed to speed things up nicely in Xcode 8 UI tests.

Comment: Wow @bejonbee shutting off "Debug Executable" for the test target sped it up a heck of a lot.. awesome

Answer (score 1):

Click on Scheme.
That is the 3 element from the top left corner. 
[image]

Uncheck the "gather coverage data" and "Debug executable"
[image]

Press close and run. :)

Hope that helps.